# How to Inject services with Async call on constructor, Angular 2

Tags: javascript, http, typescript, promise, angular

This is the problem: I have a service that makes an HTTP request in the constructor:

```js
    constructor(public http: Http, public geolocation: Geolocation) {
        this.http = http;
        this.geolocation = geolocation;
        //Http request... this will set variable forecast of the class when complete.
        this.getForecast(16);
    }
```

then I inject that service in a component like this:

```js
    constructor(public connector: ApiConnector) {
         this.forecast = connector.forecast;
    }
```

If I try to use the forecast member of the component class on the component decorator as I do here:

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    directives: [MainForecast, DailyForecast],
    template: `
        <main-forecast [main-weather]="forecast"></main-forecast>
        <daily-forecast [weather-list]="forecast.list"></daily-forecast>
    `,
})
```

> I get an error, "Cannot read property 'list' of undefined in..."

Is there any possibility to work with promises in the component constructor?

Comment: If `forecast` is a promise you should do this `[weather-list]="(forecast | async)?.list"`

Comment: It's not a promise / observable itself. But nice approach I will research and view If I can change forecast to be a promise.

Comment: It's fine if it isn't a promise or observable (I thought it was because part of your question). You can remove the `| async` and leave `forecast?.list`. See [elvis operator](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html)

Answer (score 0):

Angular2 advise to do heavy work inside **ngOnInit** NOT inside the constructor.

**ngOnInit** is a lifecycle hook / event.

Comment: *ngOnInit* is available for Components, not for Services (Injectables)

Comment: you can call an async function, you just can't await an async function in a constructor, then you can use 'then' to do your bidding

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to work around the angular lifecycle.

It seems you assume that your service is initiated during startup. This is not the case. Even if your service is provided on root level it may only be initialized just in time. You may want to call some public init method during your startup logic to ensure its initialization.